# will location information be captured when data packet is disabled on android?

Tags: android, location

Small Query.. can the locationListener able to receive location information when the user has disabled Data packet  ie. (Settings-->Wireless & Network-->Mobile Network-->uncheck data enabled) ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can use Coarse data. In that case it is using Cell area location, that will be provided by your GSM/CDMA provider.